# How to force ip change on a Windows Azure Virtual machine?

Tags: azure, ip, virtual

I'd like to know how to force an IP change on a Windows Azure machine? Calling `ipconfig -renew` seems not to be working.

Comment: Why would you need the ip to change?

Answer (score 5):

You'll get a new IP after you shutdown your machine.

E.g. click on shutdown in the portal and you should see this message:

> If you continue, the IP addresses that were assigned to this virtual machine will be released. Are you sure you want to shut down virtual machine [name]?

Comment: Yes, this is known as a Shutdown (Deallocate). Do it by performing a shutdown via portal.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you really don't have any requirement to change IP address of any Windows Azure Virtual Machine. I will try explaining more on Windows Azure IP address details.

Windows Azure Machine(s) have a fixed IP address which is internal and Windows Azure Service have virtual IP address which is publicly faced. The internal IP address is specific to each virtual machine (Cloud Service Instance or Virtual Machine Instance) which is assigned when the VM Instance is configured and stay the same during the life of Virtual Machine instance.

With Windows Azure Cloud Service Instance (PaaS) you don't have any control over Virtual Machine IP address.  However if you creating Windows Azure Virtual Machine (IaaS) you can use Windows Azure Virtual Network to put together all the virtual machines within a IP Address/Subnet group as described [here](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/create-a-virtual-network/). This may or may not be your requirement however this is one way in IaaS VM, you can put together a VM with your virtual network.

[image]

Comment: I'm building a web scrapping technology on Windows Azure and it is necessary to change the IP once in a while.

Comment: Same here. @MbServicios Did you find anything?

Comment: @MbServicios the best way so far is to shut it down, let it lose its current IP address as a result and then restart.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the deployment or cloud service, wait about 10 minuets and re-create. This will assignee a new PUBLIC IP address to the new cloud service.

Answer (score 0):

**Powershell way**
if you use Resource Manager:

```
Get-AzureRmVM | Stop-AzureRmVM -Force
Get-AzureRmVM | Start-AzureRmVM
```

or for classic VM:

```
Get-AzureVM | Stop-AzureVM -Force
Get-AzureVM | Start-AzureVM
```

Answer (score -2):

Follow the instructions at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-private-ip/

you need to restart the server